# Many-To-Many multi mapping in dapper

Tags: c#, linq, dapper

This is my database

```
Product
+----+----------+
| Id |   Name   |
+----+----------+
|  1 | Product1 |
|  2 | Product2 |
|  3 | Product3 |
+----+----------+

Category
+----+-----------+
| Id |   Name    |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Category1 |
|  2 | Category2 |
|  3 | Category3 |
+----+-----------+

ProductCategory
+----+------------+------------+
| Id | ProductId  | CategoryId |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 |          1 |          1 |
|  2 |          1 |          1 |
|  3 |          2 |          2 |
+----+------------+------------+
```

Now, I want to get all products with its categories. In my repository I added this code:

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> GetAllProducts()
{
    var products = await _dbConnection.QueryAsync<Product, Category, Product>(
        @"
            SELECT p.Id, p.Name, c.Id, c.Name
            FROM Product p
            LEFT JOIN ProductCategory pc on pc.ProductId = p.Id
            LEFT JOIN Category c on c.Id = pc.CategoryId
        ",
        (product, category) =>
        {
            product.Categories.Add(category);
            return product;
        }, splitOn: "Id",
        transaction: _dbTransaction
    );

    return products.GroupBy(p => p.Id).Select(g =>
    {
        var product = g.First();
        product.Categories = g.Select(p => p.Categories.Single()).ToList();
        return product;
    });
}
```

In results, I got list of 3 items:

- Product1 with 2 categories (Category1, Category2)
- Product2 with 1 category (Category2)
- Product3 with 1 category (null)

The problem is that I don't want Product3 to have filled category list with `null` value. What I wanted is to have empty Category list in this case. What should I do to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change the mapping function to?:

```cs
(product, category) =>
{
    if (category!=null)
    {
        product.Categories.Add(category);
    }
    return product;
}
```

That will of course fail for the `.Single()` in `GroupBy`, but how would you group by missing category anyway?

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to return the raw data from the query first and then do some processing. Then you have all logic in one place. For example:

```cs
var products = await _dbConnection
    .QueryAsync<Product, Category, (Product Product, Category Category)>(
    @"
        SELECT p.Id, p.Name, c.Id, c.Name
        FROM Product p
        LEFT JOIN ProductCategory pc on pc.ProductId = p.Id
        LEFT JOIN Category c on c.Id = pc.CategoryId
    "
    ,(product, category) => (product, category)
    , splitOn: "Id"
    ,transaction: _dbTransaction
);

return products.GroupBy(pc => pc.Product.Id)
    .Select(g =>
    {
        var product = g.First().Product;
        product.Categories = g.Select(pc => pc.Category)
            .Where(c => c != null).ToList();
        return product;
    });
```

The null check skips the `null` category that's inevitably in the SQL result set because of the outer joins.